# Weka Apriori No Large Itemset and Rules Found

Tags: associations, weka, data-mining, apriori

I am trying to do apriori association mining with WEKA (i use 3.7) using given database table
[image]

So, i exported two columns (orderLineNumber and productCode) and load it into weka, as far as i go, i haven't got any success attempt, always ended with "**No large itemsets and rules found!**"

Again, i tried to convert the csv into ARFF file first using [ARFF Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exceltoarffconv/) and still get the same message;

[image]

I also tried using database loader in WEKA, the data loaded just fine but still give the same result;

The filter i've applied in preprocessing is only numericToNominal filter;

What have i wrongly done here, i suspiciously think it was my ARFF format though, thank you

**Update**
After further trial, i found out that i exported wrong column and i lack 1 filter process, which is "denormalized", i installed the plugin via packet manager and denormalized my data after converting it to nominal first;

I then compared the results with "Supermarket" sample's result; The only difference are my output came with 'f' instead of 't' (like shown below) and the confidence value seems like always 100%;

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, OrderLine is the *wrong* column.

Obviously, the position on the printed bill is not very important.

Secondly, the file format is not appropriate.

You want **one line for every order, one column for every possible item** in the @data section. To save memory, it may be helpful to use sparse formats (do not forget to set flags appropriately)

Other tools like ELKI can process input formats like this, that may be easier to use (it also was a lot faster than Weka):

```
apple banana
milk diapers beer
```

but last I checked, ELKI would "only" find frequent itemsets (the harder part) not compute association rules. I then used a tiny python script to produce actual association rules as desired.

Comment: Thank you! seems like i exported wrong columns and i need one more preprocessing filter; I use denormalized package, like explained [here](https://weka.wikispaces.com/How+can+I+use+transactional+data+in+Weka%3F);

I have updated the question since there is differences with supermarket sample output;

Comment: Disable negative rules to not see =f rules. These are rather useless, usually: people who do not buy expensive-whiskey usually do not buy something-uncommon etc. - there are just too many such rules to generate that have 100% confidence.

Comment: Well, the only option i found to disable negative rules is to treat zero as missing values; However, it returned no large itemset found message again; Been trying to use old market basket format as well as sparse data;